# Prove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(1+u^2)\,du = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\cosh t) \cosh \frac t 2 \,dt$

Tags: integration

First, we notice $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(1+u^2)\,du = 2 \int_{0}^\infty f(1+u^2)\,du$.

I tried the substitution $\frac {u^2}{2}\mapsto -1 + \cosh t$ together with $u\,du\mapsto \sinh t \, dt$ and the limits of integration remain the same.

$u = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cosh t}{2}}$, so I get that the RHS is $2\int_0^\infty f(\cosh t) \sqrt{\frac{2}{1 - \cosh t}}dt$. What can I do from here?

Comment: Try using the definition of $\cosh x$ as $\frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}$, and think chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made some arithmetic errors. Additionally, the formula you wrote is not correct.

Using your approach, let $1+u^2 = \cosh t$; then $2u\,du = \sinh t\,dt$ and 
$$du = \frac{\sinh t}{2\sqrt{\cosh t-1}}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2 t}{\cosh t-1}}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\cosh t+1}\,dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\cosh t+1}{2}}\,dt.$$
Using the half-angle formula, it follows that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(1+u^2)\,du
    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\cosh t)\sqrt{\frac{\cosh t+1}{2}}\,dt
    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\cosh t)\cosh\frac{t}{2}\,dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $1+u^2=\cosh(x)=\dfrac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}2$  $\iff2u^2=(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2$

$\implies4u\ du=(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2})dx$

$\sqrt2u=\pm(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})$

Now $2\cosh(x/2)=e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}$